# What is my co-worker asking?

Tags: american-english

My American co-worker sent this to our group chat:

> Can an undatable man be transformed into a datable man?
>
> I am not asking if you think such a thing can be done in real life.
>
> I am asking if a real undatable man can be transformed into a datable man.

English is my second language, and I'm having trouble making sense of the last two lines.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. English is my first language, and I'm very damn good at it -- and I'm having trouble making sense of those lines, too. ... And having visited the apparent [source](http://www.okcupid.com/forum?tid=10485780544709783436), I'm still at a loss. So, apparently was the poster who put it in this form - he says it is "Clear as mud".

Answer (score 2):

An "undatable man" is man who is not a good prospect for a relationship. For example, he might be selfish, or he might be a liar, or he might be too childish.

> Can an undatable man be transformed into a datable man?
>   *(1) Is it possible that an "undatable man" can be changed into a "datable" one?*
>
> I am not asking if you think such a thing can be done in real life.
>   *(2) I'm not asking about your opinion (that whether the question (1) is possible or not).*
>
> I am asking if a real undatable man can be transformed into a datable man.
>   *(3) I'm asking if the question (1) is really possible; and I mean a "real undatable man" one.*

Comment: I like your interpretation a lot. That said, I think the person who wrote the original should have been a lot more clear, particularly in differentiating between Parts 2 and 3.